# Run a function when clicking on a parent element but NOT child element?

Tags: vue.js, dialog

I'm trying to run some code to close a modal when you click outside of the dialog box. The problem is that I have a mask that is dimming the page behind the dialog box that I am using to target the close function. It has the dialog box nested within it, so when you click on the dialog box itself, it closes it. How can I click on the dialog box normally, while still having the parent element close the modal on click?

Here's a rough idea of what I'm doing right now:

```
<div class="modal-background" @click="dialogOpen=false" v-if="dialogOpen">
  <div class="dialog-box">
    dialog content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine which element is clicked with [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      dialogOpen: true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    closeDialog(e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('modal-background')) {
        this.dialogOpen = false;
      } 
      else {
        // Dialog box was clicked
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.modal-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: fixed;
}

.dialog-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="modal-background" @click="closeDialog" v-if="dialogOpen">
    <div class="dialog-box">
      dialog content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```